# Why did my wget not die after ssh connection loss?

Tags: ssh, terminal, wget, signals

I `ssh`ed to my server and ran `wget -r -np zzz.aaa/bbb/ccc` and it started working. Then my Internet connection(at my home) got interrupted and I got worried assuming that `wget` has been `hup`ped because the `ssh` connection was lost and therefore the terminal had died. But then I `ssh`ed to my server an realized that it was still running and putting the output in `wget.log` and downloading stuff. Can someone please explain to me what might have happened here?

This is what `ps` gives me:

```
PID   %CPU %MEM    VSZ    RSS TTY     STAT START   TIME COMMAND
32283  0.6 29.4 179824 147088 ?       S    14:00   1:53 wget -r -np zzz.aaa/bbb/ccc
```

What it does (question mark) `?` mean in the column of `tty`?

Comment: Note that on a modern system running `logind`, the default behavior of `logind` is to kill (SIGTERM) all processes belonging to a user when the user logs out. So this behavior is system-specific.

Comment: @Dan My system is ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I believe Ubuntu 16.04 is a systemd/logind system, but the Ubuntu default logind.conf explicitly sets `KillUserProcesses=no`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Programs (and scripts) can choose to ignore most signals, except a few like `KILL`.  The `HUP` signal can be caught and ignored if the software so wishes to.

This is from `src/main.c` of the `wget` sources (version 1.19.2):

```
/* Hangup signal handler.  When wget receives SIGHUP or SIGUSR1, it
   will proceed operation as usual, trying to write into a log file.
   If that is impossible, the output will be turned off.  */
```

A bit further down the signal handler is installed:

```
  /* Setup the signal handler to redirect output when hangup is
     received.  */
  if (signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN)
    signal(SIGHUP, redirect_output_signal);
```

So it looks like `wget` is not *ignoring* the `HUP` signal, but it chooses to continue processing with its output redirected to the log file.

---

Requested in comments:  The meaning of the `?` in the `TTY` column of the output from `ps` in the question is that the `wget` process is not any longer associated with a terminal/TTY. The TTY went away when the SSH connection went down.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you also add the meaning of ? in tty.

Comment: Yes, learned this the hard way. Not all processes die when ssh drops. It is good to know exactly why.

Comment: Alternately, make a habit of using *screen* and nothing ever HUPs.

Answer (score 9):

**Simple**: `wget` does not abort on `SIGHUP`. It does on `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT`, though.

There is nothing on the `man` page but if you sent `SIGHUP` to a `wget` process then you get this in the terminal:

```
# in a different terminal while wget is running (with PID 12345)
kill -HUP 12345
# in the wget terminal
SIGHUP received.
Redirecting output to 'wget-log'.
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it's better if you also add the `kill -HUP pid` command to show how one can send `SIGHUP` to a process.